# when using arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames, python.exe crash

Tags: python, arcpy, arcgis-10.2, data-frame

Has anybody had this problem? this drive me crazy. what is wrong with my code?

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"D:\Project\Project.mxd")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0]
```

python crash at the last line

Comment: There's nothing wrong with you code so there must be a problem with your installation or with the mxd. Could you please provide more details? What version of ArcGIS do you use? In which version of ArcGIS was the mxd created? Is there anything special with you mxd, could you maybe send it? Where do you run the code?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am using ArcGIS 10.2. In fact, I use this function before it works fine, but today I really don't what happen.

Comment: Try renaming the Normal.mxt and Normal.gxt. If it doesn't work you should probably repair ArcGIS.

Comment: maybe you could try MxdDoctor.exe to check your  mxd

Comment: If you have a vanilla install of ArcGIS for Desktop then I suspect an uninstall/reinstall may be the quickest fix if you have unsuccessfully done standard troubleshooting like checking whether your MXD will open in ArcMap.

Answer (score 1):

We have the same problem here and are wondering if we might have some corrupt MXDs e.g. with no dataframe, but the listdataframe crashes arcpy so violently we are getting no info at all - and a try:... except.... doesn't suffice to catch the issue: the app shuts down before!

It feels like Arcpy has no management of a empty dataframe list. 
MXD doctor doesn't give 'informative info' - yes, something is wrong with the MXD, but we (and it) can't pinpoint what it is.

Edit:

-The MXD opens OK in ArcMap (working in 10.0, no way to upgrade).

-Not all MXDs crash Python at the listDataframes command: most MXDs are OK.

-Issue occurs even when there is a single dataframe in the MXD.

-Saving the MXD as a new MXD or saving a copy as a former version retains the issue: ListDataframe will crahs on all 3 MXDs.

-Copying/pasting the dataframe contents in a blank MXD gets rid of the issue.

-Normal.mxt was renamed to force ArcGIS to recreat it, that had no effect on the issue - MXDs that crashed Python still crash Python.

-Python is launched from IDLE or PythonWin (same behaviour observed), not from the ArcGIS python window. Will try from within ArcGIS and post results here.

Comment: Hi Hélène, in my case, my map is crashed, I create a new map and add the required data. After that it works. Use arcgis - desktop tools - arcgis document defragmenter to check whether the map crash.

Comment: I edited your answer to try and keep it valid but it does read a lot like a "me too".  I think both the question and answer need to be edited to specify whether the troublesome MXD can be opened in ArcMap.  If it cannot then this will be an ArcMap rather than ArcPy problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a corrupt mxd. Did you try using Save As to save it under a different name?

Mxds often can become invalid - resaving it is a good way to force a refresh of the internal properties.

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer for those MXDs that do open in ArcMap but do (also) crash the Arcpy.listdataframes command. Maybe this helps someone else too:

-Open the MXD.

-Switch to layout view, select all elements.

-In my case, a blank frame appeared when selected (it has no fill and no outline).

-Check this frame's properties: In my MXDs, the objects exhibited properties from both flat graphics (2 tabs property window) and data frames (the tick box for fast display from the data frame, and only 2 tabs from the graphics).

-Delete the object, save the MXD, and launch the Arcpy script again - with success this time.

Altogether, this is an ArcMap issue, but it is exposed only when manipulating the MXD with ArcPy.